# Listing all buckets on which a user has access

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I'm trying to list all buckets on which I've been granted access thanks to gsutil, but it seems gsutil only list buckets on which my project has been granted access. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

There is not currently a way to do this.

gsutil (and the API) can only list buckets within a single project per call.